# Why this makefile is always recompiling?

Tags: c++, makefile

I've done a makefile for a project I'm working on andd my code is allways getting recompiled, and I don't know why... I've tried adding the .PHONY to the all target but didn't work. Here is the makefile:

```
TARGET  = csv2sqlite

CXX     = g++
CXXFLAGS    = -std=c++11 -Wall -I $(INCDIR) -fdiagnostics-color=always -D_DEBUG

OBJECTS = csv.o main.o

BINDIR  = bin
OBJDIR  = obj
INCDIR  = inc
SRCDIR  = src

.PHONY:default

default: $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)

%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    @echo "Compiling dependecies..."
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c  $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@
    @echo "Done compiling $@"

$(TARGET): $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(OBJECTS))
    @echo "Linking $@ file..."
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $(BINDIR)/$@
    @echo "Linking $@ file..."

run:
    bin/$(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f obj/* bin/$(TARGET)
```

And the directory tree is:

```
project
├── inc
│   └── csv.hpp
├── src
│   ├── csv.cpp
│   └── main.cpp
├── obj
│   ├── csv.o
│   └── main.o
├── bin
│   └── csv2sqlite
└── makefile
```

Here is the complete [project](https://github.com/DanielRamosAcosta/pokemon-database/tree/c++-port) if you wanna see it. Also, what kind of improves I can do it?

Thanks!

Comment: The github project you linked does not include the code you posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here:

```
%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    ...
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c  $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@
    @echo "Done compiling $@"
```

No, you're not. You didn't build `foo.o`, you built `obj/foo.o`, so the next time you tell Make to build `foo.o`, it will see that `foo.o` does not exist and attempt to rebuild it-- with this rule, which doesn't do what it claims to do. Likewise:

```
$(TARGET): $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(OBJECTS))
    @echo "Linking $@ file..."
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $(BINDIR)/$@
    @echo "Linking $@ file..."
```

This doesn't build `$(TARGET)`, it builds `$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)`, so Make runs this rule every time it's told to build `$(TARGET)`.

The fix is simple:

```
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, csv.o main.o)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    ...
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c  $< -o $@
    @echo "Done compiling $@"

TARGET  = $(BINDIR)/csv2sqlite

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking $@ file..."
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@
    @echo "Linking $@ file..."
```